# OData (large) Metadata not working

Tags: odata, metadata

I have a REST API Backend, running in DOTNET Core 2.0 with many OData Controllers in the Database Context.

Used Versions:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0 
>  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData
>   7.0.0-beta1

The $metadata Call for the API is working, but not consistently. Sometimes it loads properly and almost instant, sometimes I do not get any Response and nothing renders.

I tried reducing the Amount of Controllers and got a difference.
I personally think there is some kind of Limit or maximum Size, because i can remove a large Entity and replace it with two small ones.

[image: This is the Serverlog] while requesting the Metadata Document.

Is there a specific limit for the metadata file in odata? Is there a way to optain addtional information about the internal request? Can i manipulate or handle the metadata route.